# Two function scope fixtures are run in reverse order

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I have such a problem, I have a fixture called appclient which is session scope, its body looks like this:
`@pytest.fixture(scope='session') def appclient(): yield SomeClass()`

then I have two fixtures to cleanup after test, `cleanup_1` and `cleanup_2`, both are set 'function' scope and both inherit from appclient fixture and have body like:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
    def cleanup_1(appclient):
    yield
    <do_something>
```

I import them all to test function(I do not use conftest for this fixtures as I am having too many there) and use them like:
`def test_1(appclient, cleanup_1, cleanup_2)`, my problem is that `cleanup_2` is always done before `cleanup_1` and I can't understand why. Only when I set `cleanup_2` scope to module, it started to work.

[image]

I tried to check if alphabetical order is a problem or some dependencies, but it seems not, I don't also understand why it seems that this fixtures are used for setup as well as there is nothing above yield statement.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is to ensure `cleanup_2` depends on `cleanup_1` --

```
@pytest.fixture
def cleanup_2(appclient, cleanup_1):
    yield
```

Comment: For reference: "Names of fixtures or tests, where they’re defined, the order they’re defined in, and the order fixtures are requested in have no bearing on execution order beyond coincidence." https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/fixtures.html#fixture-instantiation-order